# How to cancel a single animation that has been run as part of an animation set

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I have an animation set similar to this:

```
ObjectAnimator animator1 = ...;
ObjectAnimator animator2 = ...;
ObjectAnimator animator3 = ...;

AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(animator1, animator2, animator3);
set.addListener(mylistener);
set.start();
```

Is it possible for me to cancel only one of the animators above without canceling the rest of the set, say for example animator2?

Thanks very much for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for simple guess, but does animator2.cancel() help?